# ASP.Net Disable postback when user presses enter in a textbox

Tags: asp.net

I am using VB for coding. I want to disable postback when user presses enter when writing in a textbox...instead cursor should move to a new line...how do I do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you set the [`TextBox.TextMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx) property to `MultiLine`?